# Ubuntu 14.04 not connecting to network on Mustang board

Tags: networking, server

I asked this question earlier this month, and have tried using both DHCP and a static IP address on the system, but it still can't connect to any other network port, so something is either wrong with the Ubuntu installation or with the network configuration itself.  Any clues what might be preventing the network connection?  It worked just fine when I did the "tftpboot" commands and the Ubuntu installation itself, but after Ubuntu boots up, it can't communicate with the network.

I followed the instructions in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Server/Install/Mustang.